# Error while inflating item of ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

I'm getting an error while inflating a ListView.

It says 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class

But on line 7# there's only a TextView. here's the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statement_date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statement_amount"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statement_description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: IS this your custom ListVeiw cell?
In that case, try putting the same file for multiple screen support..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't `android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />` be `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />` inside your first `<TextView`?